# Java: How do I set a color in a child class?

Tags: java, colors, extends

I'm trying to set a color in a child class with getters/setters but there's a compile error.

```
//world.java
import java.awt.Color;

public class world {
    private Color color;

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

//object.java
public class object extends world {
    public object{
        setColor(new world.Color(255,0,0); //compile error
    }
}
```

I can easily solve this by importing `java.awt.Color` in the child and typing `setColor(new Color(255,0,0)`, but isn't it redundant when it's already imported in the parent? I also tried other syntax such as `setColor(world.setColor(new Color(255,0,0)))` but that gives a different error. What's the correct syntax to do this correctly?

Comment: `import` is purely syntactic.  You need one per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply

```
   setColor(new Color(255,0,0); //no compile error
```

(You have to have the `import` statement in each files you use the classes...)

Explanation:

The class at hand extends `world` - that means the setColor() method is "just there" without declaring it again. It will set the `color` instanct field of the `world` class just properly, without explicitly specifying that... Methods and fields with the static modifier are always related to the **class** itself, and not the **instances of the class**

Why is `setColor(world.setColor(new Color(255,0,0)))` not working?

This syntax is for accessing **static** methods of the `world` class - but such a method does not exist. What you have is a non-static method, which is totally appropriate in this case, as the color value is related to each instance of the class individually. So in this case, the world.setColor() syntax is not valid.

<sub>GameObject swapped for world, as per OPs comment</sub>

#### Some rules to take

- Class Names Start With Capitals
- Don't use names that are similar to, or exactly like JDK library classes. **Especially true for Object, String, and the like!!!**

Comment: Cannot find symbol class Color in class object (unless I import java.awt.Color into the child). Am I supposed to do that even though I imported in the parent?

Comment: Yes, you have to do that... This is not like coding in PHP, or C, the classes are totally separate entities from that opoint of view.

Comment: As for `setColor(GameObject.setColor(new Color(255,0,0)))`, GameObject is a typo and it's supposed to be world. I'm just trying to write a clear and concise example of my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `new world.Color(255,0,0);` is incorrect in quite some ways. For the Java compiler you request a inner static class named Color for the class named world. It wont result in a compile error if you add this to your codebase:

```
//world.java (different to World.java)
class world {
    public static class Color {
         public Color(int r, int g, int b) {}
    }
}
```

So you can correct this by using `new Color(255, 0, 0);`.

And also an import statement is not a redundancy. In Java every java file defines a compilation unit. This unit stands for itself. Every class you reference by type (class/interface directly named) must be resolvable by only knowing the package name, the class name and its definitions (inner classes / interfaces, annonymous classes etc). Since Color comes from a distant package the compilation unit (your java-file) must contain a reference to the class Color. This can be done by using the import statement or referencing the Color class by its full name (= package + "." + class-name) meaning java.awt.Color.

Answer (score 0):

No, an `import` is not redundant simply because it was specified in the file containing the superclass.  The `import`'s scope is the source file in which it's located.  A subclass (or any other class for that matter) located in a different source file needs its own imports.

You can `import java.awt.Color;` again in the child class source file, and refer to `Color` by its simple name.

```
setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
```

Or you can supply a fully-qualified reference when needed:

```
setColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
```

The [JLS, Section 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) has this to say on the scope of an import:

> The scope of a type imported by a single-type-import declaration
>   (§7.5.1) or a type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2) is all the
>   class and interface type declarations (§7.6) in the compilation unit
>   in which the import declaration appears, as well as any annotations on
>   the package declaration (if any) of the compilation unit .

By "compilation unit", it means the source code file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Color class is not a member of world, so `new world.Color(255,0,0)` is not valid. In that point, you can only say `new Color(255,0,0)`.

That is to say, that the even though your `world` class is importing `Color`, it is not defining `Color`.